# how to add sql query to log4j file

Tags: log4j

how to add sql query to log4j file..   am using oracle 10g simple jdbc application..(i.e register,login information,etc in queries..to logfie )

```
 # Log levels
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO,CONSOLE,R
    # Appender Configuration
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    # Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
    # Rolling File Appender
    log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'DD-MM-YYYY
    # Path and file name to store the log file  E:/logs
    log4j.appender.R.File=D:\\log4j\\log\\my4.txt
    log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=200KB
    # Number of backup files
    log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=2
    # Layout for Rolling File Appender
    log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %c - %p - %m%n
    log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm} %c  %M  (%F:%L)-%m%n
```

Comment: import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

Comment: am importing above one..

Comment: i want what are query executed that should be store in  \\log4j\\log\\my4.txt               file so what is the configuratrion..